# Where could my packets be being blocked?

Tags: windows, networking, streaming, wireshark, udp

I am working on a video streaming project, I have issues when sending above a certain amount of traffic (something like 20 Mbs) I no longer receive any packets. Some quick facts:

- Windows task manager shows a spike in the traffic to the 20Mbs number and then crashes down (see pic)
  [image: Spikes]
- I have a 1Gbs connection to my router, and I hit 800 MBs on my laptop connection
- The packets are coming in UDP
- I am seeing packet loss in both my own code, and in wireshark
- Both the sender and receiver are running Windows (Server 2019 & 11 respectively)

The spike and then drop in the Windows receive leads me to believe that the traffic could be being blocked somewhere, but I am not sure where.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are the two computers connected and through which routers?

Comment: One is ethernet in a data centre and one is wifi to a linksys router